# Need a model instance for a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to use this method

```
   public function givePermissionTo(Permission $permission)
     {
        return $this->permissions()->save($permission);
     }
```

So i can assign a permission to a role, for example:

```
$role->givePermissionTo(Permission::first());
```

However, what i get when trying to use that method is a bad method call exception.

My attempts to access that method were:

```
$role = Role::whereName('editor')->skip(1)->take(1)->get();
```

I have tried it in many other ways, but my problem is that i cannot get an instance of the Role Model, so i can access that method and give it the permission.

Comment: $role = Role::whereName('editor')->skip(1)->take(1)->get(); is the model that you try to retrieve? and after this you are doing: $role->givePermissionTo(Permission::first()); ? because if it so, the problem is that if you want a model you should call first() and not get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want to get a an exact role, you have to use first() method instead of get().
Try:

```
$role = Role::whereName('editor')->skip(1)->take(1)->first();
```

After assign the permission to the role you got:

```
$role->givePermissionTo(Permission::first());
```

Comment: I didn't use first because i made some duplication, so i wanted to skip the one with the id of 1.

Comment: @DanielSantos first() doesn't get the first model from the table, it gets the first model from your results.  get() will always return a collection.

Comment: The problem he is trying to give the permission to a collection instead of a row.